# Call SQL Server Reporting Services from MS CRM workflow activity

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

My task is to generate printable report within MS CRM 2011 interface.

Is there any recommended way to access SQL Server Reporting Service within CRM hosted code? I don't want to connect directly, since it requires passing correct credentials to correct URL — and this information differs from installation to installation.

So I either need to create setup table to save all connection information, or I should hard-code it and recompile.

Is there any generic solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way I found is to use Reporting Services endpoint and credentials to access it. I wrote article about it - http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2012/11/general-approaches-to-generation-of.html

Comment: Just to add - you can add some configuration entity to store settings like endpoint address, credentials and so on and use it inside custom workflow activity.